# Postponing the plot to the following notebook cell

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to have this code organization

```
# 1st cell showing my intentions
plt.plot(t, f(t))

(NO OUTPUT)
```

and

```
# 2nd cell with boring details
plt.xlabel(...)
...
plt.show()

(the plot with all the now interesting details)
```

because I plan to use the notebook to produce slides and/or pdf using an extension that allows to hide the input cell only, so that my reader sees only
what I want to show of my code ­— they can look at the notebook itself to see what's going on behind the scene…

I've tried `plt.hold()` but it's not what I had in mind…

Comment: You may capture the output of a jupyter cell by putting `%%capture` in the first line of it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It seems to me that the implementation of `%%capture` is buggy — following `%%capture my_plot` I should be able to access a member `my_plot.outputs` containing the rich display obiects that I can pass to `display`, but it does not work, IPython raises an exception if I try to access that property.   Further, I suspect that the object that is saved is a bitmap of the plot rather than the matplotlib `ax`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. My suggestion was to use `%%capture` without any appenix.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  I want to suppress the plot in a cell and in the next cell I want to modify it and eventually display the modified (in my example i added an x label) plot. ፨ I built on your comment, that did not address this side of my problem, trying to find a solution to _my problem_.  Do my previous comment make sense now?

Comment: I currently don't see the problem. Capture the output from the first cell, but don't capture the output from the second.

Comment: I guess [this is what I'm talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118059/how-to-add-plot-commands-to-a-figure-in-more-than-one-cell-but-display-it-only).

Comment: Or better [the complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760693/how-to-overlay-plots-from-different-cells).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Your 1st comment was not helpful (trust me). The links to your previous answers, on the other hand... especially the `%config InlineBackend...` trick!